# jQuery UI Sortable, on Sort Start, how to blur out of field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI sortable for a list of items that are contenteditable divs.

On sort start, when a user clicks and drags a drag.handle, it's possible that the contenteditable could be in focus. I want to blur as soon as sorting starts.

How can this be done? The list items look like:

```
<li class="listItem" id="list_item_510" style="display: block; ">
<div contenteditable="true" id="list-item-510-contenteditable">XXXXXXXXasdadsasdasdasdads</div>
<input class="list_item_title" maxlength="250" name="list_item[title]" type="text" id="list-item-510" style="display: none; ">
<span class="drag-handle">change order</span>
</li>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not seeing this behaviour in my testing: http://jsfiddle.net/zLW2q/. A suggestion though would be to set the contenteditable attribute on a `.dblClick()` event as that seems more natural to me.